# jQuery: .children()[index] not allow function invocation

Tags: jquery, function, indexing, children

Why does this not work...

> > $('#parent').children()[3].html('Content');
>
> **Doesn't work**
>   TypeError: $("#parent").children()[3].html is not a function.

when this does?

> > var x = $('#parent').children()[3].className;
>
> **Does work**

An example is found at my now-mashed [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/lastchild-vs-child-class)

Thanks.

Comment: use `$("#parent").children().eq(2)` rather than `$("#parent").children()[3]` to receive a jQuery object rather than the DOM element object (without jQuery functions)

Comment: Duplicate of [$(element)\[index\].addClass(); does not work](/q/49314884/4642212) (which is higher quality).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$("#parent").children()[3]` gives you a native DOM object, not a jQuery object, and `html` is not a property on DOM nodes, but `className` is. Use `.innerHTML` to get the inner HTML.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/VUXyZ/1/)

```js
alert($("#parent").children()[2].innerHTML);
```

or

```js
alert( $("#parent").children().eq(2).html());
```

Comment: Yep. That works fine. I'm guessing that I have access to the DOM properties but not the jQuery functions. Ah, you just edited your post to say as much :)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. You may be interested to check the updated jsperf to compare the speed of all the options :)

Comment: Further testing shows that using `.innerHTML` in an attempt to either read or set the html contents FAILS :)  That's why it's so fast - 'cos it ain't doin' nothin'!!